# Preloading translation .json

Tags: observable, angular7, ngx-translate

I'm trying to pre-load my translations. I decided to use a guard to be sure the page title will be properly set and it's working almost fine.

The only problem I'm facing is that, sometimes, the translate.use within the forEach loop takes longer than the one that comes outside it, which result in a wrong page language.

How can i implement a logic which would allow me to run these 3 translate.use on after the other?

```
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

import { map, switchMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Injectable()
export class TranslationGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private translate: TranslateService,
    private titleService: Title) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {

    const languages = ['Italiano', 'English', 'Español']

    this.translate.addLangs(languages);

    this.translate.setDefaultLang('Italiano');

    const languageToUse = 'Italiano' // static value for the example

    languages.filter( i => i !== languageToUse).forEach(i => {
       this.translate.use(i);
    })

    this.translate.use(languageToUse);

    return this.http.get('/assets/i18n/' + languageToUse + '.json')
      .pipe(
        map( (translations) =>  {
          const pageRoute = route.routeConfig.path.toUpperCase();
          this.titleService.setTitle(translations[pageRoute].PAGETITLE);
        }),
        switchMap(  () => of(true) ),
        catchError(  () => of(false) )
      );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue transforming my observables in promises, but it looks weird.
Is there a prettier solution?

```
    languages = languages.filter( i => i !== languageToUse);

    this.translate.use(languages.pop()).toPromise()
       .then( _ => {
        return this.translate.use(languages.pop()).toPromise();
      }).then( _ => {
        return this.translate.use(languageToUse).toPromise();
      });
```